# Maven: No plugin found for prefix 'dockerfile'

Tags: maven, docker

followed some maven docker examples, came up with following code, run
 mvn package dockerfile:build
but get these errors:
[ERROR]  No plugin found for prefix 'dockerfile' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompnay.learning</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app-base-pom</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>


    <properties>
        <dockerfile.version>0.0.1</dockerfile.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>AdminService</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <repository>docker.io/kkapelon/docker-maven-comparsion</repository>
                            <tag>projectVersion</tag>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Where should i go from here pls ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most probably get the error because the plugin (which is version `0.0.1`) is missing. Check for any `maven` warnings

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.spotify:dockerfile-maven-plugin:jar:0.0.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for ...
```

Because it fails to retrieve the plugin descriptor, maven does not know there is a `dockerfile` prefix configuration associated with the plugin and hence the error "*No plugin found for prefix*" comes up. This configuration is stored in the plugin's path on the `maven` repository

> The conventional artifact ID formats to use are:
>
> - **`maven-${prefix}-plugin`** - for official plugins maintained by the
>     Apache
>     Maven team itself (you must not use this naming pattern for your
>     plugin, see this note for more informations)
> - **`${prefix}-maven-plugin`** for plugins from other sources.
>
> If your plugin's artifactId fits this
>   pattern, Maven will automatically map your plugin to the correct prefix in the  metadata stored within your plugin's groupId path on the
>   repository.

More about plugin prefix resolution [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-plugin-prefix-mapping.html)

For version [1.4.0](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/spotify/dockerfile-maven-plugin/1.4.0/dockerfile-maven-plugin-1.4.0.pom), for example, the descriptor (i.e. `pom` file) 
has a configuration section:

```
<configuration>
    <goalPrefix>dockerfile</goalPrefix>
    <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound> 
</configuration>
```

Changing the version to something more recent (>1.2.0) should fix the error.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            ...
        </plugin>
```

Run with:

```
mvn package dockerfile:build
```

Comment: if i want to run integration test, is there a way to do it using spotify ?

Comment: You cannot run the container using spotify if that's what you intend. I would reccomend [fabric8](https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin) plugin for that.

Comment: another related question if you know   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57105061/hows-spotify-dockerfile-maven-plugin-uses-docker-compose-build